# Getting results from first element of foreach

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, foreach

There are many matching credentials inside the table which are inserted to an foreach loop however I am getting the results only from the first foreach element. How could I fix that?

```
    foreach($matches as $match)
    {
        $object = $match->object;

        $sales->whereRaw("match (`object`) against (?)", array($object));

        if($match->colourBase == '1')
        {
            $sales->where('colour', '=', 'CC');
            $sales->orWhere('colour', '=', 'CC+DD');

            if($match->maxPrice)
            {
                $sales->where('price', '<=', $match->maxPrice);
            }

            if($match->minPrice)
            {
                $sales->where('price', '>=', $match->minPrice);
            }
        }
    }

    $results = $sales->orderBy('sales.updated_at', 'asc')->get();
```

**@update**

This is how I get $matches

```
 $matches = Match::where('PeopleID', '=', $id)->get();
```

Comment: why are you using match->colour == 1

Comment: @coder Sorry, I've done a mistake while getting the code. Its now corrected.

Comment: Update your question with $matches array

Comment: @DsRaj is right what your doing to get $matches array is more important as unless its erroring its most likely how your getting that which is wrong.

Comment: @MarkDavidson   Could you have a look please

Comment: Do a `dump($matches)` or `->count();` check how many results there actually are.

Comment: @MarkDavidson It looks like I am getting the results for $matches it is just when I do that foreach, it does not want to show me all results from $sales . $matches contains search information and all I want to do is look for $sales which are equal to $matches credentials.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one record 
use `first()` function.
No need to use foreach. :)

```
$matches = Match::where('PeopleID', '=', $id)->first();
```